# Windows Azure Cloud Service cant deploy with 2.2 SDK, WAHostBootstrapper crashing

Tags: azure

So updating our webroles to SDK 2.2 gave us some problems.

The webroles do not start as WAHostBootstrapper crashes before starting them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that visual studio dont set the dll to Copy Local. It used to work without copy local, but the 2.2 dll is not in the GAC.

Setting Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime as copy local made the webroles work again.

Comment: If it crashes, its 99% sure its something with missing dlls. If someone else run into the problem.